# "New" is to "novelty" as "archaic" is to...?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, analogy

Is there a noun form of the word "archaic"? The closest word I can think of is "old-fashionedness" but it seems rather clumsy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe **archaism**

> a thing that is very old, or old-fashioned

Comment: +1 for maintaining the etymological relationship in the analogy. You can add "archaicism" to that. You should cite your source (even though it's easy to find).

Comment: @Jim But that does not work.  Look at the model of *new* to *novelty*.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it some more. I noticed, from the online etymology dictionary, that "new" has diverged from the latin "novus" considerably, if that is indeed its source. Am I incorrectly assuming they are linked (new->novus), seeing how they are mentioned together there? (Or are you referring to the dimunuitive referene to "novellus"?) What troubled me afterword is that "archaic" is not so divergent from the greek "arkhaikos" as "new" is from "novelty".

Comment: Jim: no, @tchrist was saying that 'old' and 'archaic' are not cognate.

Answer (score 4):

*New* is to *novelty* as *archaic* is to ***antiquity***.

Comment: Don't know why  this is downvoted.. It is a legitimate answer.

Comment: It is a correct answer to the question as summarized in the question title, but the body makes clear the question is about a noun form of the word "archaic".

Comment: @MετάEd If you were right, this would be too simple a question to answer, since anybody can look up *archaic, archaical, archaically, archaicism, archaicist, archaism,
archaist, archaistic, archaistically, archaize, archaizer, archaizing* in any dictionary. Mine is a perfectly correct answer: as *novelty* is the Latinate form of something that is *new*, so too is *antiquity* the Latinate form of something that is the opposite of *new*.  *Novelty* opposes *antiquity*.  What, you want *neo* and *paleo* instead?  He pointed the way at Latin, not at Greek.

Comment: @MετάEd, Since "old-fashionedness" was proposed as an answer, but rejected only for clumsiness, I think it's clear OP *didn't* just want an answer that's grammatically a noun-form of archaic.

Comment: I took to question be be about an analogy rather than merely a word or phrase meaning... There are many words that might fit the meaning. But where is the challenge in that beyond general reference?

Comment: @tchrist I understand your reasoning in your response to MετάEd. It would have been helpful (and I thought it is expected) if you had stated this approach in your answer. (I doubt if the OP really gave it that much thought, though ;) )

Comment: +1, though I'd add that some senses of *novelty* correspond more with *antique* than *antiquity*.

Answer (score 3):

*“New” is to “novelty” as “archaic” is to* **passé**

> [**passé**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pass%C3%A9) dated; out of style; old-fashioned

Answer (score 0):

There are two uses of the word *novelty*. One is for an intangible characteristic of something, and the other is for the thing itself. Your suggested answer of "old-fashiondness" suggests you're thinking of the first usage.

In that case, I'd suggest *quaintness*. From dictionary.com we have

> **quaint** adjective, quaint·er, quaint·est.
>
> 1. having an old-fashioned attractiveness or charm; oddly picturesque: *a quaint old house.*

with *quaintness* as a derived form.

However, I believe that UK and American usage of *quaint* may be different. I'm answering from an American perspective.

Comment: And if the poster has the other sense of _novelty_ in mind, a suitable match might be _relic_.