# Word for something that used to be popular but not anymore

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that simply means *something that used to be popular but is no longer*.

I do not want the word to denote that **it is not as good as it once was**

ex:

- Obsolete: no longer in use or no longer useful

Whether or not it is still very important, just that the popular attention has shift away, is up for the context.

The closest thing I could find was:

- It's so yesterday: something that is out of fashion

But that's slang and (for me, at least) gives a small implication that it's not as good as whatever is the new thing now.

Edit: I found:

- Old-School: used, usually approvingly, to refer to someone or something that is old-fashioned or traditional

However, I'm not sure if 'old-school' could be used for some political thought/opinion.

Are there any other single-word adjectives that could describe this?

Sample Sentence:

> When I showed my dad a trending music video, he took one look at it and said "My goodness, this is so ______! It's so nice to see this kind of music video again - it really takes me back to my younger days."

Edit:

I've realized that my example give off a positive connotation, so 'old-school' would be closer than any other word I've found - but I'm looking  for a word with a neutral connotation as to why it's no longer popular.

Comment: Re your edit at the end: *passé* has a negative connotation, not a neutral one. Calling something passé criticises it (whereas "old-fashioned" can go either way or be neutral depending on the context and tone).

Comment: Related and possible duplicates: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/72520 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/187975 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/391081 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/150192 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/256227 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/216346 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/105052 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/126722 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/300933 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/468760 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/177327 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/318820

Comment: Well done the people that voted this a duplicate! Now ask yourselves why none of the answers to this question are the same as those to the question that you voted it a duplicate of.

Comment: Umm... Is the duplicate even related to this question?

Comment: @David  Lots of the related questions have the same answers as this one. I could only pick five of them for the duplicate marking. This question is not adding value to the site by attracting expert answers with original content — instead it's just drawing mindless copypasta thesaurus spam just like most of the related and possible duplicates have done.

Comment: @Justin Yes, the related questions share suggestions duplicating ones here like *passé, old-fashioned,* and *vintage*.  I could only pick so many to mark as duplicates. We’re trying to build up a library of ***expert answers*** containing orginal content. We are not a thesaurus service, especially not for the same guessing *qua* popularity game again and again and again.

Comment: @tchrist — You are right of course. It’s unsatisfying getting lots of votes for an off-the-cuff reply, whereas an extensive original hypothesis about the use of units and numbers is ignored. But that’s the way it is. Even worse on Biology.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> [passé](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/passe?s=t)

[pa-sey; pah-sey]

adjective

1. no longer fashionable, in wide use, etc.; out-of-date; outmoded :

*There were many photographs of passé fashions.*

*I thought hand-cranked pencil sharpeners were passé.*

Comment: There is no explanation here. We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: This exactly matches what's being looked for by the question title and most of the body of the question. (I am choosing to ignore the example sentences because they match neither with each other or the rest of the question.) I also completely disagree with the earlier comment—clearly, there are multiple lines of text here, along with explanations and context, so +1.

Comment: The examples are the dictionary examples and exemplify how "passé" is used as an adjective before a noun as well as a predicate adjective, which is how it seems to be most typically used and, notably, how the question's only two examples would use it.

Comment: Please see our [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). This post provides little value to the site because there’s no original content here, no reason given in your own words as to why you think this is the answer. ELU is not a link-farm for thesaurus copy-pasta text. We expect expert answers, not just copies of others’ words whether attributed or not. You still have to write your own answer in your own words.

Answer (score 20):

Similar to **passé** is the term ***[dated](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dated)*** (Collins) which may seem less freighted.

adding: The difference (to my ear) between **passé** and **dated** is that the former has an implication of fashion, faddism or popularity (which the OP did refer to), while the latter is more neutral, meaning only "from an earlier time".

Comment: Note that dated has the connotation that it's been a long time since the thing was popular.

Comment: "Freighted"? Well I suppose it rhymes. (But at least dated is English.)

Comment: @David - All words carry some baggage, eh? To my ear, *passé* has associations with fashion or popularity, where *dated* just implies "of an earlier time", so it's more neutral.

Comment: Don’t get me wrong, I think dated is better than passé. I was really commenting because you used the word “freighted” which was new to me.

Comment: To me *dated* just means it's of another time, not that it was necessarily popular in its time.

Answer (score 11):

[**“Old-fashioned”**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/old-fashioned) is the old-fashioned way of saying “old-school”.

e.g. *They have a very old-fashioned management structure.*

This is generally negative in implication, as in the above, although not always:

e.g. *I’m an old-fashioned girl.*

**“Out of fashion”** is a more neutral phrase that is actually used in the question to define a slang alternative.

e.g. *Fur coats have gone out of fashion.* (From the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fashion?q=out+of+fashion))

I actually think it is more neutral than *passé*, which is just the French for  old-fashioned, would only work with an audience of a certain education, and may soon become *passé*.

[**“Unfashionable”**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unfashionable) is a single word that is a also *more neutral* than old-fashioned. This can be seen in the following example:

*Although extremely unfashionable at the moment, group selection is an attractive theory when one is presented by data such as this book contains.*

The writer is making a positive statement about something that is unfashionable.

Answer (score 6):

Old-school tends to have positive connotations (like, 'Oh cool, that's so old-school!'), passé tends to have negative connotations (like, 'Ugh, that's so passé.'), retro is the most neutral (which fits your example, like old-school--probably the only ones that would really be used in that scenario). Though this means that it is used again (maybe popular or not so much), but with a trending video in your example, that's the case you are looking for. Though in most cases of things being in style, the question is often if something is in style now. So one can have something from recent times that can be old-school, passé, or retro. But if you are referring to something that exists only in the past, old-school or passé would apply, but not retro. Dated is often used to say someone's views are no longer well accepted (and are unlikely to be popular again, if they ever were that popular), but can apply to other things, like methods no longer used. Vintage generally just means something that is old, but doesn't always mean it was popular before.

retro
/ˈretrō/

adjective

imitative of a style, fashion, or design from the recent past.
"retro 60s fashions"

noun

clothes or music whose style or design is imitative of those of the recent past.
"a look that mixes Italian casual wear and American retro"

Answer (score 5):

I think **vintage** is pretty neutral and close to what you're looking for.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vintage):

> adjective
>   ...
>   3 a : dating from the past : OLD
>      b : OUTMODED, OLD-FASHIONED

Comment: Please see our [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). This post provides little value to the site because there’s no original content here, no reason given in your own words as to why you think this is the answer. ELU is not a link-farm for thesaurus copy-pasta text. We expect expert answers, not just copies of others’ words whether attributed or not. You still have to write your own answer in your own words.

Answer (score 4):

***Démodé*** could also be used in this context -

> ## Démodé
>
> /deɪˈməʊdeɪ/
>
> adjective
>
> : *no longer fashionable*

Example sentence -

> *An old-line French restaurant with stodgy food and a **démodé** décor
> straight out of the 1950s*.

([Meriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/d%C3%A9mod%C3%A9))

Comment: I’m thinking that you had best use *décor* with an acute accent mark correctly placed over the *e* if you’re going to use them correctly on the word immediately preceding to it.  Just be glad *décor démodé* is masculine in French not feminine like *cuisine démodée* or else you’d’ve had to’ve spelt it differently. :)

Comment: @tchrist - Thanks for pointing it out! Edited to make changes.

Answer (score 3):

If *yesterday* is too informal, then you won’t like this too much. However, specifically for pop-culture references like your music video example, you can describe it by the decade it represents:

> that hair is so 70s
>
> those shoulder pads are so 80s

These very clearly connote past and passed popularity, while also providing a bit more specificity.